# потоки в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Попросили меня сисадмины написать скрипт который выключает все компьютеры в локальной сети. Вроде как я это сделал, но он по очереди для каждого хоста прописывает команду shutdown /s /t 0 /m \ip_address; Получается очень долго. Где то не получается приконнектиться к компьютеру, где то тайм-аут и т.д  С Threading я познакомился буквально вчера. Пожалуйста, подскажите как сделать так, чтобы shutdown для каждого компьютера стартовал в отдельном потоке. Время поджимает. Спасибо!

Comment: потоки не обязательны, чтобы несколько внешних команд параллельно выполнять.[Python threading multiple bash subprocesses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14533458/4279)

Comment: Там более ста хостов. И для каждого хоста выполняется команда. Где то не получается приконнектиться к компьютеру, где то тайм-аут и т.д; ПОКА PYTHON НЕ РАЗБЕРЁТСЯ С ОДНИМ ХОСТОМ, К ДРУГОМУ ОН НЕ ПЕРЕХОДИТ.

Comment: Если я не прав, извиняюсь

Comment: в ссылке, которую я привёл выше, показано как запустить несколько команд одновременно.

Comment: Да, разобрался.

Comment: Этот кусок кода вроде работает как я хотел, но пожалуйста, посмотрите и скажите, этот код рабочий?

`def main(hosts):
     for el in target_hosts: 
         try:
             command = r'shutdown /s /t 0 /m \\{}'.format(el)
             resp = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
         except:
             pass
 main(target_hosts)`

Comment: @Nikto Добавьте его в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, у тебя есть ip адреса всех компьютеров, поэтому смотри:

Тебе в threading'e для этого дела важна только функция Thread, поэтому особо можно не разбираться в этом модуле (хотя он интересный на мой взгляд). И, естественно модуль os, иначе как ты будешь использовать командную строку в питоне)

```
from threading import Thread #импортируем функцию из модуля threading, для работы с потоками
from os import system #импортируем функцию из модуля os для работы с командной строкой

ip_adresses = (...) #Тут кортеж из ip адресов, сделай их в строчном формате, мало ли, там есть ip адрес, начинающийся на 0. Можно было бы использовать и список, но, если эта программа будет выполнять только отключение компьютеров, то, думаю, для небольшой экономии памяти, мы выделим кортеж, а не список.

def shutdown(ip_adress): #создаём функцию, которую будем передавать потокам для выполнения, которая будет выключать компьютера
    system('shutdown /s /t 0 /m \\' + ip_adress) #функция, которая будет обращаться к командной строке и выключать компьютер с ip адресом ip_adress. Важный момент: обратную косую черту мы удваиваем, иначе будет ругаться у нас питон (p.s. в итоге она будет восприниматься питоном как одна обратная косая черта)

for ip_adress in ip_adresses: #создаём цикл, который будет обращаться к каждому ip адресу в нашем кортеже
    Thread(target=shutdown, args=(ip_adress,)).start() #создаём поток, в котором передаём цель - функцию shutdown, объявленную выше, и аргументы в кортеже (в данном случае аргумент) - ip_adress, из переборки кортежа с ip адресами. Указываем после ip_adress запятую, чтобы питон не ругался на то, что нужно передавать кортеж. Не заносим этот поток ни в какую переменную, потому что с ним в дальнейшем работать не будем и сразу указываем в конце .start(), дабы сразу его запустить.
```

Как-то так

Comment: Спасибо, но я просто использовал subprocess.Popen()
Эта функция выполняет системные команды в МНОГОПОТОЧНОМ режиме.